# Как лучше всего организовать хранение настроек сайта и отдельного пользователя в Symfony 6.3?

Tags: php, ооп, symfony, settings

Всем привет. Имеется сущность User. В ней обычные поля - $id, $name, $email, $gender, $avatar и.т.д.
Возникла необходимость создать настройки пользователя сайта - тема(светлая/тёмная), получать ли рассылку и т.д.
Пихать все эти настройки прямо в сущность, насколько я понимаю, не совсем правильно. Как в этом случае лучше всего поступить? Создать отдельную сущность Settings с полями id, user_id, theme, send_mails? И подтягивать её по связи OneToOne? Или есть лучший вариант?

И второй вопрос в том, как хранить настройки сайта для админа. Создавать отдельную сущность Configuration с полями id, setting_name, value ? А как же тогда инжектить объект Configuration со всеми настройками сайта в классы?

Comment: Если по конфигурации не нужны поиски и прочая, то храни конфигурацию в одном поле как json.